# slick slider sync thumbnails not aligning (on Shopify)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify, slick.js

I've installed Slick sliders synced slides for product images and thumbnails and it all works fine until you use the main image to navigate instead of the thumbnails.

You can see the issue here:
https://monosnap.com/file/2wLtDBErumVnQs8UlA5PtRro8UBQZq

It's run on Shopify but I don't think that would be the issue it's more something to do with centring but I just can't figure it out!

Any help appreciated!

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    $('.slider-for').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: true,
      fade: true,
      asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
    });
    $('.slider-nav').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      asNavFor: '.slider-for',
      dots: false,
      centerMode: true,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      infinite: true
    });
  });


        <div class="slider-for">
          {% for image in product.images %}
          <img src="{{image | img_url: '565x', crop: 'center'}}" title="{{image.alt | default: product.title | escape}}" alt='{{image.alt | default: product.title | escape}}'/>                          
          {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <div class="slider-nav">
          {% for image in product.images %}
          <div>
            <img src="{{image | img_url: '400x'}}" alt="{{image.alt | default: product.title | escape}}" class="product-thumbnails">
          </div>                          
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
```